# Permalinks WordPress .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

What does `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` exactly do? My guess is that its' an optimization rule which basically states that if the requested file is `index.php` it will not go through all the other rewrite rules and just provide it as it is. Therefore, skipping 2 conditions, thus speeding it up. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

This is the best explanation, from inactive blog (randomtype.ca/blog):

"This particular rule is easy to understand: if the path is index.php then perform no replacement (that’s what the dash means), and exit out of the apache rewrite loop.

The final part of the rule [L] tells Apache to stop processing any remaining rules.

While this rule may seem silly, hang on to it in the back of your mind, because we’ll come back around to it."

Still you can find some [cached copies](http://web.archive.org/web/20130704085124/http://randomtype.ca/blog/the-wordpress-htaccess-file-explained) of this explanation of whole wordpress .htaccess

Comment: Well, that is what I was thinking but what is the point of it since `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` already does that? (thus, only slowing it down).

Comment: Have you read linked text? There is an explanation: "Well it turns out that [L] does not stop rule processing, instead Apache skips the remaining rules on its current pass..." Please read it. It's really great tutorial.